# is there any way to limit number of clients (IPs) to connect a port ? (ubuntu 22)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, iptables, port

I'm trying to find a way to limit the number of IPs that can connect to a certain port. here is a simple example that returns the number of unique IPs connected to a port

```
netstat -ntu | grep :80 | grep -v LISTEN | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | wc -l
```

or maybe a script with one condition can refuse connections from a new IP when the code above meets the condition.

or maybe it can be done with iptables

I also saw this code

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -dport 80 -m iplimit --iplimit-above 10 -J REJECT
```

but I didn't find any document for iplimit or --iplimit-above

Comment: In the server program, or probably in nftables (or the older iptables).

Comment: The best documentation for those that I know of is in the netfilter documentation at: https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 1):

Among [*iptables* extensions](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html), the [`connlimit`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#connlimit) match can do this:

> `connlimit`
>
> Allows you to restrict the number of parallel connections to  a
> server per client IP address (or client address block).

It was [initially called `iplimit` but was renamed (in 2003!) `connlimit`](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=59cbe17cee0499c8f25a8d9f29513f4c85e9b03c):

> rename iplimit to connlimit

It relies on the *conntrack* subsystem which tracks the current state of ongoing established connections, so this match can also be used in a router (including a system hosting containers or VMs) in filter/FORWARD rather than only on an end node in filter/INPUT.

Your example would translate into:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 -j REJECT
```

The default is to apply the limit per single source address:

> `--connlimit-mask` prefix_length
>
> [...] If not specified, the maximum prefix length for the applicable
> protocol is used.

meaning /32 for IPv4 and /128 for IPv6

> `--connlimit-saddr`
>
> [...] This is the default [...]

For a global limit the additional option `--connlimit-mask 0` can be used:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT
```

As OP's initial command excluded 127.0.0.1 an exception should be inserted before so these connections won't be accounted in the next rule, for a final (non optimized) result of:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT
```

One could replace `-s 127.0.0.1` with `-i lo` or even have a previous rule immediately allowing all of `-i lo` which is common etc.

---

The `-p tcp --syn --dport 80` block is broadly equivalent to `-p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate new`. `--ctstate new` could be used for other datagram-oriented protocols (UDP, ICMP ...) once default timeouts are considered. For example, to limit answering to two (globally) ongoing received pings (ICMP echo request) at the same time:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 --connlimit-mask 0 -j DROP
```

Note: as *conntrack*'s entries timeout at 30s with ICMP, a "slot" will require 30s to be available again and allow a new `ping` command to get replies once one of the two previous allowed `ping` commands was ended.